# WCAG 3.2.4: "export", "refresh", "add" buttons on different pages allowed?

Tags: accessibility, wcag

I have "export", "refresh" and "add" buttons on different pages. The "export" button exports content of the current page. "Add" adds items depending on the page a user is on (users, servers etc.) and "refresh" refreshes the current page.

Is that allowed according to WCAG 3.2.4? Or do I need to rename things in "add user", "add server", "export users", "export server"...

Thanks,
Thorben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fourth example on the [*Understanding Success Criterion 3.2.4: Consistent Identification*](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/consistent-identification.html#examples) article that's part of the W3's WCAG 2.1 spec seems analogous:

> An e-commerce application uses a printer icon that allows the user to print receipts and invoices. In one part of the application, the printer icon is labeled "Print receipt" and is used to print receipts, while in another part it is labeled "Print invoice" and is used to print invoices. The labeling is consistent ("Print x"), but the labels are different to reflect the different functions of the icons. Therefore, this example does not fail the Success Criterion.

Rather than just labeling the icon "print" and letting users infer what it prints from the context of the page, they've labeled it differently in each specific context.

This would suggest that you should label your buttons "add user", "add server", etc.

Comment: thanks - I missed that example somehow

Answer (score 0):

Its not a WCAG failure, if same button label is not used for any other functionality (means 3 "add" buttons are there in page but has different functionality to add user, add admin, add project etc.)

Its best if we describe the purpose in text.